# Calculate days/time(h:m:s) from 2 datetimepicker in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datetimepicker

I have a windows form with a button, textbox, and 2 datetimepicker,
the datetimepicker has been customize to display date with time,

what I want is to calculate the difference between the 2 datetimepicker when clicking the button and the output will be displayed on the textbox, the output should display the difference of days, hours, minutes, seconds, if the difference is not more than 1 day, then the output should be hours, minutes, seconds.

EDIT:

```
 DateTime startTime = dateTimePicker2.value;
 DateTime endTime = dateTimePicker3.value;

 TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks);
```

this code already works, but it displays additional random numbers at the end.

also I have this code to customize the datetimepicker to display date with time but it does not display the "AM/PM"

```
dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
```

is there a missing code here thats why the AM/PM does not appear?

TIA, I also continue on surfing to find some answers.

Comment: If it gives the answer in seconds, you can manually calculate all the fields easily enough.

Comment: Well, I'd split the problem up into two parts, first. Are you able to get the values out of the pickers correctly? If not, the rest of the code doesn't matter and you should focus on that. If so, the pickers part is irrelevant, and you should focus on the part that's *just* about the `DateTime` values and we don't need any aspect of the GUI in the question. A console app would make it easier to reproduce the problem and see what's wrong. Please edit your question to focus on *just* the part that's causing problems.

Comment: Also, you should start thinking about time zones - are you interested in the difference in elapsed time in a particular time zone? Because (say) 00:30 to 02:30 isn't always two hours - it could be one hour or three hours, if the clocks went forward or back by an hour during that time.

Comment: As @JonSkeet mentioned, the problem here might be something else than the calculation itself, since that part should work. To get the value from the DatePicker, you should use `dateTimePicker2.Value` instead of `dateTimePicker2.Text`

Comment: ill edit the question to be more clear

Comment: editing it to .value instead of .text works, see my edited version of question, but the problem is why does it displays random additional number at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this code already works, but it displays additional random numbers at the end.

The `ToString` of `TimeSpan` returns the result formatted with the common format specifier ("c") which is `[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]`

`fffffff` is (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx))

> The optional fractional portion of a second. Its value can range from "0000001" (one tick, or one ten-millionth of a second) to "9999999" (9,999,999 ten-millionths of a second, or one second less one tick).

You can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) for the custom format of `TimeSpan`.

If you want only the days, hours, minutes and seconds you would use:

```
duration.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

---

If you are still using older framework than .net 4, you will not find this overload of `ToString`.

What you can do then is:

```
string result = string.Format("{0}.{1}:{2}:{3}",
    duration.Days,
    duration.Hours,
    duration.Minutes,
    duration.Seconds)
```

Comment: .ToString shows error after adding the @"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss, error: No Overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

Comment: Which .net version are you using?

Comment: It's time to move on :) This `ToString` method was introduced in .net 4

Comment: is it okay to use version 4.5, will it affect my program?

Comment: Check also my update, if you are limited to .net 3.5

Comment: @user7254740: In future, please note in the question when you're using *such* an old version of the framework. (.NET 4 was released in 2010. It's reasonable for anyone to *expect* you to be using a reasonably up-to-date version unless you specify otherwise in the question.)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to recreate you scenario with the actual `DateTimePicker` control, since the code on itself should work (as others mentioned, there is no need to use ticks, but it works all the same).

What I did notice however is the time format you are using, which is:

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Since you access the value as "Text" from the control and your OS might be running on a Culture where this is not the default DateTime format, an exception with the conversion can occur.

E.g. if you try to convert 5/13/2017 - as May 13th 2017, but your OS default culture expects the format 13/5/2017 for this date - a `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime` Exception can happen. The code would also return an incorrect duration when you input dates May 10th and May 11th, since the program would interpret these dates as October 5th and November 5th.

To avoid this you can use `datepicker.Value` to get back a `DateTime` from the control therefore eliminating the need for the conversion.

So the code would look something like this (with the display to the textbox):

```
DateTime startTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime endTime = dateTimePicker2.Value;

TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks);

textBox1.Text = duration.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: tried this sir, it outputs right but why its displaying additional number? e.g, -1.00:00:00.2831698   where the additional random number 2831698 came from?

Comment: That is the number of ticks of the difference between the dates. To remove it you can use this `duration.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");`. I'll update the answer

Comment: .ToString shows error: No Overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument